# Magento Cloud local installation issues!

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3, magento-cloud

I was trying to set up a Magento cloud development environment on my local computer. Please let me know if Am I on the right track or any additional steps I am missing out. Thank You.

**The following steps I did follow:**

- Clone cloud repository.
- Switch to the `integration` branch and create a new `integration2` branch.
- Dump the remote database and import it locally
- Download the remote `app/etc/env.php` file and change the database credentials.
- Synchronize with parent envirnment using `magento-cloud environment:synchronize integration`
- Install the modules using `composer --no-ansi --no-interaction install --no-progress --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader` command
- Update modules using `composer update`
- Build the environment using `magento-cloud build` command

**The errors I am getting right now.**

**Browser Error**

```
An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.
```

**Terminal Error**

```
The command "php ./bin/magento module:enable --all --ansi --no-interaction" failed. Warning: include(/Users/user/Sites/hoodslym2/vendor/composer/../../generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/Proxy.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/user/Sites/hoodslym2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 571
run <scenario>...

The hook failed with the exit code: 11

Build complete for application mymagento
Web root: /Users/user/Sites/hoodslym2/_www

Cleaning up...
```

**var/log/cloud.error.log**

```
{"errorCode":1008,"suggestion":"Check if your cloud template contains latest php.ini configuration file https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud/blob/master/php.ini","title":"File php.ini does not contain opcache.blacklist_filename configuration"}
{"errorCode":1006,"stage":"build","step":"validate-config","suggestion":"No stores/website/locales found in config.php\n  To speed up the deploy process do the following:\n  1. Using SSH, log in to your Magento Cloud account\n  2. Run \"php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools config:dump\"\n  3. Using SCP, copy the app/etc/config.php file to your local repository\n  4. Add, commit, and push your changes to the app/etc/config.php file","title":"The configured state is not ideal","type":"warning"}
{"errorCode":15,"stage":"build","step":"compile-di","suggestion":"Check the `cloud.log` for more information. Add `VERBOSE_COMMANDS: '-vvv'` into `.magento.env.yaml` for more detailed command output.","title":"The command \"php ./bin/magento setup:di:compile --ansi --no-interaction\" failed. \u001b[32m%message%\u001b[39m 0/9 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 151.0 MiB\r\u001b[2K\u001b[32mProxies code generation...\u001b[39m 0/9 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 151.0 MiB\r\u001b[2K\u001b[32mProxies code generation...\u001b[39m 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% 3 secs 157.0 MiB\r\u001b[2K\u001b[32mRepositories code generation...\u001b[39m 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% 3 secs 157.0 MiB\r\u001b[2K\u001b[32mRepositories code generation...\u001b[39m 2/9 [======>---------------------]  22% 36 secs 352.0 MiB\r\u001b[2K\u001b[32mService data attributes generation...\u001b[39m 2/9 [======>---------------------]  22% 36 secs 352.0 MiB\r\u001b[2K\u001b[32mService data attributes generation...\u001b[39m 3/9 [=========>------------------]  33% 37 secs 354.0 MiB\r\u001b[2K\u001b[32mApplication code generator...\u001b[39m 3/9 [=========>------------------]  33% 37 secs 354.0 MiB\r\u001b[2K\u001b[32mApplication code generator...\u001b[39m 4/9 [============>---------------]  44% 1 min 378.0 MiB\r\u001b[2K\u001b[32mInterceptors generation...\u001b[39m 4/9 [============>---------------]  44% 1 min 378.0 MiB\r\u001b[2K\u001b[32mInterceptors generation...\u001b[39m 5/9 [===============>------------]  55% 4 mins 466.5 MiB\r\u001b[2K\u001b[32mArea configuration aggregation...\u001b[39m 5/9 [===============>------------]  55% 4 mins 466.5 MiB","type":"critical"}
{"errorCode":11,"stage":"build","step":"refresh-modules","suggestion":"Try to run `composer update` locally. Then, commit and push the updated `composer.lock` file. Also check the `cloud.log` for more information. For more detailed command output, add the `VERBOSE_COMMANDS: '-vvv'` option to  the `.magento.env.yaml` file.","title":"The command \"php ./bin/magento module:enable --all --ansi --no-interaction\" failed. Warning: include(/Users/user/Sites/hoodslym2/vendor/composer/../../generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/Proxy.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/user/Sites/hoodslym2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 571","type":"critical"}
```

**var/log/debug.log**

```
[2023-02-06 13:12:41] report.ERROR: Error: Application is not installed yet.  [] []
[2023-02-06 13:12:43] report.CRITICAL: No key available {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No key available at /Users/user/Sites/hoodslym2/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php:262)"} []
```

**Development Environment**

```
Magento 2.4.3-p1
PHP 7.4.33
Composer 1.10.26
MySQL 5.7.29
NGINX 1.23.3
Elasticsearch 7.8.1
macOS Monterey 12.4
```

Comment: Use warden > https://docs.warden.dev/environments/types.html#magento-2

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps on how I set up my local:

1. Clone Magento cloud repo
2. **composer install**
3. **php ./vendor/bin/ece-patches apply**
4. Run the **warden env up**
5. Import db

Ready to go. Super simple to handle local env with server config

Comment: I have some limitations using docker currently. I will definitely check this out. I'm grateful for your assistance.

Comment: You can try steps 1, 2, and 3 and treat them as other Magento installation

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

- `magento-cloud environment:synchronize integration` takes action on the remote cloud environments, not local.
- `composer install` is appropriate for local setup as it maintains version control. `composer update` is not appropriate, and should only be used if the intent is to update the versions of all modules.
- `magento-cloud build` is not appropriate for local setup. It works exclusively on the Magento Cloud infrastructure.

Probably the main problem comes from running `magento-cloud build`. Reset your branch and run build commands manually. If Magento is in developer mode, the only one you really need is `composer install` and `bin/magento setup:update`. And, maybe a cache clearing or reindexing along the way.